# Computer vision algorithms for binary classification of bird images

Tags: computer-vision, binary-classification

I want to start a project to detect if an image is a crow or not a crow (crow as in the black bird). Is this referred to as "binary classification?" If I wanted to use open source Python libraries, what kind of algorithms/concepts/libraries should I be researching? Are there any datasets that could be useful for this classifier? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is binary classification as you only have two classes. Generally, "binary classification" is referred to as classification. If you have more than two classes, it is called multi class or multi-nominal classification. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification) provides both a summary of what binary classification is and a short introduction into methods you can use to get started.

If you're looking for a specific python library to get started, I recommend [Keras](https://keras.io/getting_started/). It is quite easy to use and they provide good examples to get started. This is an example for binary classification of cats and dogs: [Classification from scratch for cats and dogs](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/)
You can adapt it for your own dataset.